# Why is calling a constexpr function with a member array not a constant expression?

Tags: c++, templates, constexpr

I have the following helper function:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::size_t Length(const T(&)[N]) {
    return N;
}
```

Which returns the length of a static array. In the past this always has worked but when I do this:

```
struct Foo
{
    unsigned int temp1[3];
    void Bar()
    {
        constexpr std::size_t t = Length(temp1); // Error here
    }
};
```

I get an error when using MSVS 2017:

> ```
> error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
>
> note: failure was caused by a read of a variable outside its lifetime
>
> note: see usage of 'this'
> ```

I was hoping someone can shed light on what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Unrelated, but you might as well make `Length` `noexcept` as well - there's no reasonable scenario where it would ever throw an exception.

Comment: Seems to work ok on [gcc](https://wandbox.org/permlink/yBXcDHvE7VuR7m3B).

Comment: Looks like an MSVC bug to me. This should be a constant expression, I do not see any reason why it would not be.

Comment: @SergeyA That sucks, guess I'll send a bug report

Comment: @super: No, it doesn't work in GCC: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/927ce1d01daf819e. GCC without `-pedantic-errors` might allow it because it supports VLA in C++. With `-pedantic-errors` it fails in C++17 GCC as well.

Comment: What specific version of the MSVC 2017 compiler are you using? They've been releasing updates frequently with various standard conformance improvements. Also, what C++ standard version are you building the code as?

Comment: @super Changing the code to "constexpr std::size_t t = Length(temp1)" causes an error

Comment: @JesperJuhl The latest update, with C++17 enabled

Comment: @Jarann put the exact compiler version number in the question. "Current" *now* and in 5 years will probably be very different (and the question should still make sense then).

Comment: @JesperJuhl Sorry, version 14.14.26428

Answer (score 21, accepted):

MSVC is correct. `Length(temp1)` is not a constant expression. From [[expr.const]p2](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#2.1)

> An expression *e* is a core constant expression unless the evaluation of *e*, following the rules of the abstract machine, would evaluate one of the following expressions:
>
> - `this`, except in a constexpr function or a constexpr constructor that is being evaluated as part of *e*;

`temp1` evaluates `this` implicitly (because you are referring to `this->temp1`), and so you don't have a constant expression. gcc and clang accept it because they support VLAs as an extension (try compiling with `-Werror=vla` or `-pedantic-errors`).

Why isn't this allowed? Well, you could access the underlying elements and potentially modify them. This is completely fine if you are dealing with a `constexpr` array or an array that is being evaluated as a constant expression, but if you are not, then you cannot possibly have a constant expression as you will be manipulating values that are set at run time.

Comment: If you want to test standard validity of the code with GCC, then tiptoeing around its numerous extensions with narrow-targeted `-Werror=vla` would make little sense. The proper combination of flags in such cases is `-std=...` and `-pedantic-errors`.

Comment: @AnT While I completely agree that disabling extensions generally is the way to go, we were *specifically* talking about VLAs here, so I thought I'd just mention that warning option (`-Wvla`) specifically. Also, sometimes, getting rid of extensions in a codebase has to happen one extension at a time to be practical.

Comment: Your answer sounds rather roundabout... I think the direct way of answering this question would be "the compiler does not account for the fact that you disregard the actual element values, which are not constant expressions".

Comment: @Jesper Juhl: Yes, I agree in general. I'm just saying that in this specific case when I compile this in GCC without `-pedantic-errors` I don't even get a warning. It is completely silent. I.e. there's no reason for me to even begin to suspect that something is wrong, let alone worry about something as specific as VLA.

Comment: @Mehrdad That makes it sound like a quality of implementation issue. But a compiler that accepted this code without any diagnostic message would technically be incorrect.

Comment: @aschepler: Huh... I don't see it that way, but ok.

Answer (score 4):

```
Length(decltype(temp1){})
```

[seems to work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9634fc8b73b9b574).

Unfortunately, I cannot comment, but Mehrdad 's solution is wrong. The reason: it is
not *technically* undefined behavior **but** it *is* undefined behavior. During constexpr evaluation, the compiler must catch undefined behavior. Therefore, [the code is ill-formed](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d8b4033d4c6c8c60).

Comment: The code is ill-formed, and as my link above shows: gcc rejects it. So, there is not extension.

Answer (score 1):

Your question's already been answered, but in terms of how to "fix" it, a quick-and-dirty way is to replace

```
Length(temp1)
```

with

```
Length(*(true ? NULL : &temp1))
```

which I think is *technically* undefined behavior but practically going to work fine for MSVC.

If you need a solution that works despite the UB, you can change `Length` to use a pointer:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::size_t Length(const T(*)[N]) {
    return N;
}
```

and then you can use `Length(true ? NULL : &temp1)`.

Comment: Is it more of an extension then UB? Because UB in a constant expression results in ill-formed, which the implementation can side-step with an extension.

Comment: @Rakete1111: That seems plausible but I really don't know. I was just trying to provide a workaround in case someone needed to get code working (which I tested for MSVC).