# MSVC and constexpr for function parameter?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, constexpr

This code compile fine with clang and gcc.

```
template<size_t n>
struct N {
    static constexpr size_t v = n;
};

template<size_t n>
constexpr bool operator<(N<n>, size_t n2) {
    return n < n2;
}

template<typename N>
constexpr void foo(N v) {
    static_assert(v < 5);
}

int main()
{
    foo(N<3>{});
    return 0;
}
```

However, if I use MSVC, I got the error that `v < 5` is not a constant expression. I can understand why MSVC thinks that, but I think it is wrong and clang / gcc are right. Is it a bug from MSVC?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50917360/why-is-calling-a-constexpr-function-with-a-member-array-not-a-constant-expressio

Comment: @RbMm Please correct me if I'm wrong, but `this` is never evaluated (explicitly or implicitly) here.

Comment: @CássioRenan - here common not in `this` but in *failure was caused by a read of a variable outside its lifetime*. here `v` instead `this`

Comment: What if you do `const N v`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, MSVC is wrong here.

It may seem counter-intuitive that the code is well-formed, because how can `v`, which is not a constant expression, possibly be used in a constant expression?

So why is it allowed? Well first, consider that informally, an expression is not a constant expression if it evaluates to a glvalue that is itself not a constant expression or a variable that started its life outside of the the enclosing expression ([[expr.const]p2.7](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#2.7)).

Second, `operator<` is `constexpr`.

Now, what happens is that `v < 5` is a valid constant expression. To understand that, let's go through the evaluation of the expression.

We have:

1. `v < 5` calls your `constexpr` `operator<`
2. The two parameters are copied (both of them literals and none evaluate to a non-constexpr object)
3. `n2` started its life within the evaluation of `v < 5` and is a literal
4. `n` is a non-type template parameter, as such usable in a constant expression
5. Finally, `n < n2` invokes a builtin operator.

All of those do not violate any of the points in [[expr.const]p2](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#2), so the resulting expression is in fact a constant expression that be used as an argument to `static_assert`.

Those types of expressions are known as [converted constant expressions](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#5).

Here's a simplified example:

```
struct Foo {
  constexpr operator bool() { return true; }
};

int main() {
  Foo f;
  static_assert(f);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

MSVC is incorrect here, let's start with a simplified version of the code:

```
struct N {
    static constexpr size_t v = 0;
};

constexpr 
  bool operator<(N n1, size_t n2) {
    return n1.v < n2;
}

  void foo(N v) {
    static_assert(v < 5, ""); // C++11 does not allow terse form
}
```

We will look at the `static_assert` first, have we violated any rules for constant expressions? If we look at [[expr.const]p2.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.const#2.2):

> an invocation of a function other than a constexpr constructor for a literal class or a constexpr
>   function [ Note: Overload resolution (13.3) is applied as usual —end note ];

We are good, `operator<` is constexpr function and the copy constructor for `N` is constexpr constructor for a literal class.

Moving to `operator<` and examine the comparison `n1.v < n2` and if we look at [[expr.const]p2.9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.const#2.9):

> an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) unless it is applied to
>   - a glvalue of integral or enumeration type that refers to a non-volatile const object with a preceding initialization, initialized with a constant expression, or
>   - a glvalue of literal type that refers to a non-volatile object defined with constexpr, or that refers
>   to a sub-object of such an object, or
>   - a glvalue of literal type that refers to a non-volatile temporary object whose lifetime has not
>   ended, initialized with a constant expression

We are good here as well. In the original example we are referring to a template non-type argument which is usable in a constant expression so the same reasoning applies to that case as well. Both operands of `<` are usable constant expressions.

We can also see that [MSVC still treats the simplified case as ill-formed](https://godbolt.org/z/7_o0Yw) even though clang and gcc accept it.

Comment: Giving a constexpr copy constructor makes everything works. Thats Magic https://godbolt.org/z/hqefvo :')

Answer (score -1):

If you had declared:

```
template<size_t n>
struct N {
  int i;
  static constexpr size_t v = n;
 };
```

Demo [here](https://godbolt.org/z/SFp42v).

Both MSVC, Clang and GCC would reject your code. The reason is that `v` is copied into the first parameter of `operator<`. Such a copy is an evaluation of `v` and `v` is not a constant expression.

In your case `N` is an empty class. I don't think the standard specifies if the copy constructor of such a class should access the memory of the object <sup>1</sup> ([core language issue 1701](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_active.html#1701)). So the compilers showes a behavior that depends on whether or not the memory of object of empty class is accessed.

Clang and GCC, does not access the memory of object of empty classes when passed has parameters, but MSVC does: see this [compiler explorer link](https://godbolt.org/z/pmutg-)

So I think all compilers are right.

---

<sup>1</sup> Accessing the memory representation of the object to copy padding bits would involve a `reinterpret_cast` (or equivalent) which is also forbiden in constant expression.

Comment: To check the const-ness of an expression, the standard only cares whether an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion occurs. It does not care whether the memory is accessed.

Comment: @xskxzr Hehe and when are lvalue-to-rvalue applied, even the standard is not clear if it happens here: [core issue 2103](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_active.html#2103)

Comment: @xskxzr And if padding bit are copied, is it through a reinterpret_cast, because this is also forbidden is constant expression? Are you sure the standard does say that padding bit are not copied (this is issue 1701).

Comment: @xskxzr I added a note to explain what else than lvalue-to-rvalue conversion could happen!

Comment: @xskxzr I understand that this was not the intention of the those who write the standard. The standard is a formalism, it is incomplete and inconsistent (like any complex and interesting formalism) but still it is much more consistent than than can be none phrased intentions!

Comment: What does CWG1701 have to do with a copy constructor accessing memory? The copy constructor is defined in terms of members/bases that it copies. No base/members => no copying.

Comment: @Rakete1111 On the other end a memcpy of the object representation => copying all subojects, (or not copying any suboject if there are no). So under the as if rule, it would apply with a small difference, which is that under this special case, this copy using memcpy can not be (until c++2a maybe) constexpr. This special case has been overlooked. The Note below issue 1701 talk about that, are padding bits constituent of the object?

Comment: @Oliv But memcpy is not and cannot be used. The copy constructor copies base/members and under the as-if rule, the compiler is allowed to replace that with a memcpy, but not a compile time, as that would violate the as-if rule.

Comment: @Rakete1111 Yes you are right. I am a 100% GCC user, I have no intention to be the advocate of MSVC, but here I can't say that MSVC is wrong, it associates memory to empty object, and then copy this memory when such empty object are parameters. So it accesses the memory representation of the object. lvalue-to-rvalue conversion means getting the value (the prvalue)). The memory representation is formed of value bits and padding bits, but what of what is formed an empty object. I am looking in the standard and cannot find anything.

Comment: @Oliv The thing is, there is no memory access because we are in compile time, not runtime. MSVC most likely doesn't store anything for an empty object, and even if it does, it doesn't matter, because as the class is empty, nothing is being evaluated. The copy constructor is a no-op. At runtime MSVC can do whatever it wants, but compile time it's different. There is no lvalue-to-rvalue conversion happening on any subobject of the class. With `i`, there is one, and that's why with `i` the code is invalid.